# Why is the output of OPAMP coming as 2.239V?

Tags: output, calculation

[image]

What formula can be used to get this output?
I tried using superposition theorem but the output is not coming the same.
Considering V1 off and V3 at 3V : V- = 3V (2k/5.32k) = 1.128V
Considering V3 off and V1 at 3V : V+ = 1.5V (voltage divider)
Thus OPAMP output : 1.5V x [1+(2.49k/2k)] - 1.128V x (2.49k/2k)
=> 3.3675 - 1.404 = 1.9635V (but its showing 2.239V why?)

Comment: [Edit] your question to show your attempt so that someone can point out where you've gone wrong.

Comment: Why 3V (2k/5.32k) and 1.5V x [1+(2.49k/2k)]?  It should be 3V*(2.49k/3.32k) = -2.25V  And if we turn off V3 we have 1.5V * (1 + 2.49k/1.25k) =  4.48V Thus,  **Vout = 4.48V -2.25V = 2.23V**

Comment: If V1 is off, IN+ has 0 V (ignoring small offsets) and the circuit will force IN- to 0 V as well, not 1.128 V. However, you can translate V3, R79 and R77 into a voltage source of around 1.128 V with a series resistance of 1.248 kohm feeding a current into virtual GND. This current will also flow through R75 and lets you calculate the (in this case negative) output voltage. With V1 on you calculate similar with 1.5 V at IN-.

Comment: Thanks @G36 for solving my doubt :)

Comment: Thanks @Jens :)